# How to make sure user on on the right login page before they continue?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing, ux-designer

So we currently have two different types of devices, and each device has its own login page/URL. Our customers have been getting confused as to which url they need to access for which device they have. Device type A has 6 models and device type B has 4 models. I need a way for the user to recognize they are on the wrong url depending on what device they are looking for and a way to redirect them.

For example, if my user has both model types, but wants to access model Type B he may accidentally open the model Type A URL. In that case, I want the user to see some kind of check, like "make sure you are on the correct login page (show list of models)" and be able to redirect to the correct url. I cant find a way to do this without making my login page too cluttered. I would like to keep it the standard "username, pass, forgot pass, sign up" without adding too much to overwhelm the user. Is there a way to get this info across while minimizing the space it takes?

Rough wireframe for reference:

[image]

Comment: Can't you autodetect and serve the appropriate Login form?

Comment: @Devin That is a great idea, but at the moment I am not sure our technical team is up to that task. I was told a landing page to select which domain to go to would be difficult, so the solution would be best if we used just these two urls and nothing else.

Comment: these devices are generic? For example smartphones, tablets or desktops

Comment: @Devin Basically yes, generic devices with their own unique serial number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can auto-detect the device using media queries or device identification through User Agent. However, if this is not possible, I wouldn't complicate it much and go for a no-thrill version: simply state the device in the title and offer an option to change the URL, and that's it.

I made a quick wireframe below so you can see what I mean:

[image]

Comment: That seems like what I'm looking for, for the most part. I think I will have to fine tune it a bit to fit my requirements, as you are not logging into a specific device but rather the type. So you login to type A which has multiple models under that, and device type B which has a different set of models. The user doesn't always know which type their model is, so I will have to add additional info to show that "these models are type B, want to login? click here" but I think this is on the right track